# How do I install Skype on a domain computer so that anyone who logs in does NOT have to go through the initial config?

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-server-2008, skype, domain

I installed Skype when logged on to the (local) admin account. Now, when I log off that, and log on as myname on the domain, I have to click through the intial setup steps (after you've already run the installer) of Skype. So, I have to click next to get through the mic setup/test, and it asks me if I want to take a pic.

How do I get it so that any person who logs in can just open Skype and go straight to the login screen?

Windows 7 64 bit, 2008R2

Comment: Might this be better off at [sf]?  Please don't cross-post.  A moderator will migrate, if appropriate.

Comment: Good question for the MS Skype forum as well

Comment: It got closed on Server Fault. Is there a way I could migrate it or do I just wait around hoping they'll do it?

Comment: @Matt - You already posted here, its better left closed or even deleted, since having two questions is in bad taste.